# How do I add a decimal before the last 2 characters using PHP

Tags: php

Okay now I have a problem that I need to add a decimal before the last two digits of a number for example.

Current Number

```
29200
```

Desired output

```
292.00
```

I currently dont know how to go about this.

Comment: try this `echo number_format(29200,2,'.','');`

Comment: This adds an extra two zeros at the end of the decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilities:

```
echo number_format(29200/100,2,'.','');
echo preg_replace('/(\d\d)$/', '.$1', 29200);
printf("%.2f", 29200/100);
echo bcdiv(29200, 100, 2);
```

Output (for all)

```
292.00
```

Links to the various manual pages: [`bcdiv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php), [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)